# Fill half of SVG circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following circle SVG:

```html
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
     <rect width="40" height="40" fill="#f8ab29" rx="20" />
      <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Geomanist-Book" font-size="27">
      <tspan x="16.369" y="29.348">1</tspan>
      </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would like it to be half grey half orange. (bottom part orange, top part grey).

```html
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
   <mask x="0" y="0" id="half">
    <rect y="50%" fill="grey" width="100%" height="50%" />
   </mask>
   <rect mask="url(#half)" width="40" height="40" fill="#f8ab29" rx="20" />
     <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Geomanist-Book" font-size="27">
     <tspan x="16.369" y="29.348">1</tspan>
     </text>
</svg>
```

But it doesn't work and half bottom is being painted in added grey layer instead of the top part.
Any help?

Comment: Is there a reason you used a rectangle with a radius rather than a circle?

Comment: no reason, this is how the graphic designer gave it to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Comment: How could I flip this so it's left right as opposed to up down? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is multiple ways of doing this. One way is to create a circle and then a path which resembles half a circle overlays it:

```html
<!-- Using overlaying path -->
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#f8ab29" />
      <path d="M0, 20 a1, 1 0 0, 0 40, 0" fill="gray" />
      <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Geomanist-Book" font-size="27">
      <tspan x="16.369" y="29.348">1</tspan>
      </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You could also use a linear gradient to achieve the same effect:

```html
<!-- Using gradient -->
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <defs>
<linearGradient id="half" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
  <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="#f8ab29" />
  <stop offset="50%" stop-color="gray" />
</linearGradient>
  </defs>
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="url('#half')" />
  <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Geomanist-Book" font-size="27">
  <tspan x="16.369" y="29.348">1</tspan>
  </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```